# How to calculate straight line into graph having variety of different results

Tags: graphing-functions, functional-equations

How to calculate straight line into graph having variety of different results. What I mean for example let say we have this kind of results (measuring persons weight `(w)` and height `(h)`):

```
w1 = 100 and h1 = 180,
w2 = 100 and h2 = 200,
w3 = 70 and h3 = 170,
w4 = 65 and h4 = 180.
```

So here we would get plot graph. And having these results, how to calculate straight line that would best match all these results? Do I need to get an average of these results and then use formula `y = mx + b` or what?

Comment: this is called linear regression.

Comment: You choose $m$ and $b$ to minimize $\sum \left( y_i - ( m \cdot x_i + b) \right)^2$ See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) for how

Comment: @WarrenHill thanks. That was what I was looking for.